# Setting the mime-type for files stored in the private directory

Tags: 7, files

How do I set the mime-type of files being served from the drupal private directory. I have a webm file in the private directory, and the I've added the `<video>` tag to the page using a *tpl* file.

I've tried adding

```
AddType video/webm .webm
```

to .htaccess. I've also tried installing the module "File Mime" to try to set the right mime type. I've tried adding

```
function mymodule_file_download($uri){
    return array('Content-type: '.'video/webm');
}
```

to my .module file. Nothing seems to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Editing `includes/files.mimetypes.inc` is a core hack, which you should [strive to avoid](http://drupal.org/best-practices/do-not-hack-core).

Instead, use [hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_mimetype_mapping_alter/7):

```
function mymodule_file_mimetype_mapping_alter(&$mapping) {
  // Add new MIME type 'video/webm'.
  $mapping['mimetypes']['webm'] = 'video/webm';
  // Add new extension '.webm' and map it to the 'video/webm' MIME type.
  $mapping['extensions']['webm'] = 'webm';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured this out myself: I had to add the webm mimetype in the appropriate places in the `includes/files.mimetypes.inc` file to get drupal to serve private files with the correct mimetype.